# Unable to set elements in an Application Layout control (XPages)

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

Ok, I have two custom controls:

- MainLayout: Contains an Application Layout control (from the Domino extension library)
- Section1: Contains a section with a header and a few items

Now I create a new XPage, and drag the MainLayout control on it.

Now I want to drag Section1 to the page, and connect it to LeftColumn area of the MainLayout... which seems like something trivial, but I can't get it to work for some reason.

When I drag the section1 control to the leftColumn area, the component is always getting inserted at the top of the page. The little pencil-icon next to "LeftColumn" seems decoration-only to me, because no matter if you left-click or right-click on it, nothing happens...

How is this supposed to work?

Update:

This how my xpage looks like after adding the MainLayout control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xc:MainLayout></xc:MainLayout>

</xp:view>
```

XML of the MainLayout custom component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:oneuiApplication titleBarName="Test"
                    placeBarName="Server1" legalText="YadaYada">
                <xe:this.footerLinks>
                    <xe:userTreeNode label="User 1"></xe:userTreeNode>
                </xe:this.footerLinks>
                <xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
                    <xe:loginTreeNode label="Login 1"></xe:loginTreeNode>
                </xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
                <xe:this.placeBarActions>
                    <xe:basicContainerNode label="Select server">
                        <xe:this.children>
                            <xe:basicLeafNode label="Server1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                        </xe:this.children>
                    </xe:basicContainerNode>
                </xe:this.placeBarActions>
            </xe:oneuiApplication>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: do you have any xml source code? in the Application Layout, the LeftColumn area is a editable area, in the xml source code shown as a facet, with a key="LeftColumn"

Comment: added xml, but I don't see anything that indicates a facet declaration.

Comment: In the properties of the layout control you can tick if you want to use  editable areas for the 3 main columns. That adds the facets. Of course you can add them manually. Get the book.

Comment: stwissel: that was exactly what I was looking for :-) Thank you very much! Too bad I can't mark a comment as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a custom where i use the application layout.
in my custom control I have above the configuration tag the following code
[image]

And in my XPage which use my custom layout I referer to my LeftColumn editable area by the following code
[image]

Comment: I don't have those facet-declarations. I even tested it by creating the la out from scratch. Did you add that code yourself? If so, where did you find the documentation for that?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the application layout need these facets

Comment: I have tested again. You can leave the facets in your custom control. But in your xpages you need to referer to the LeftColumn, see the second screenshot in my answer.